# vb.net Rename table in access database

Tags: database, vb.net, oledbconnection

I am making an application where i want to rename access database table. I connected to database with OLEDBConnection and I chose table with textbox.Text which i created when I register. In another form I should change an username but when i do it, my select table system will crashed.

So the question is how can i rename table in access database?

(I watched some tutorials, but microsoft MSDN is not clear for me)

This is code which i use to rename username:

```
  pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = Z:\Password manager\Password 
  Database\Database.accdb"
    connstring = pro
    myconn.ConnectionString = connstring
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE LogIN SET [Meno]='" & txtName.Text & 
     "',[Heslo]='" & EncryptText(txtPass.Text) & "',[E-mail]='" & txtMail.Text & "' WHERE  
      Meno= '" & txtName.Text & "'", myconn)
    If myconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then myconn.Open()

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        MsgBox("Your name was changed")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
    myconn.Close()
    My.Settings.LogINSetting = txtName.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ADOX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/adox-api/adox-objects?view=sql-server-ver15) to do so. In your Project, add a Reference to **Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security** (it's under COM) and use the [Catalog Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/adox-api/catalog-object-adox?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
Dim ADOXCatalog As New ADOX.Catalog

ADOXCatalog.ActiveConnection = myconn
ADOXCatalog.Tables("CurrentTableName").Name = "NewTableName"
```